# Unable to install NVIDIA driver on various GCP Ubuntu VM's with Tesla K80 GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, nvidia

I have followed [this GCP guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu) with Ubuntu 18 and 20 (have also tried Ubuntu Lite, Debian and Centos 7) but, unfortunately, after completing the lengthy install I get this:

```
me@gpu:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running
```

I have tried installing via the script and via the direct downloads from the Nvidia site for Cuda 10. Ready to pull my hair out if that helps! I don't understand how a company that builds a bazillion GPU's can't make the installation process robust?

I have also tried [these recommendations](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldn-t-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-after-updating-ubuntu-20-04/170985/4) with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working. The mistake I was making was not doing the pre-installation steps before running the cuda_10.1.243_418.87.00_linux.run script. I was under the impression the *.run file would do everything for me. It would help if users were told they MUST do the pre-installation steps. Specifically I had to do this for Ubuntu 18:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
sudo update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

This seems like a bit of a “hack”, so not sure why nvidia can’t make the installation process more robust? They make a bazillion of these cards. It’s not like some homemade product with a niche user base…

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the driver so many times and `nvidia-smi` is still failing to communicate, take a look into `prime-select`.

1. Run `prime-select query`, this way you are going to get all possible options, it should show at least `nvidia | intel`.
2. Select `prime-select nvidia`.
3. Then, if you see `nvidia is already selected`, choose a different one, e.g. `prime-select intel`. Next, switch back to nvidia `prime-select nvidia`
4. Reboot and check `nvidia-smi`.

Plus, it could be a good idea to run again:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

When it finishes, reboot the machine, and nvidia-smi should work then.

Now, in other cases it works to follow these instructions to install CuDNn and Cuda on VMs [cuda_11.2_installation_on_Ubuntu_20.04](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73).

And finally, in some other cases it is caused by unattended-upgrades. Take a look into the settings and adjust them if it is causing unexpected results. This URL has the documentation for Debian, and I was able to see that you already tested with that distro [UnattendedUpgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades).